# what happen if we are in an untrusted network

Tags: security

I am discovering Iota and I am trying to find out if I it can be applied to securely send command between  iot device, being 100% sure the command has been received. My concern is about the network, what happen if we are in an untrusted network with man-in-the-middle attack, arp spoofing or things like that ?